# How to detect video orientation when we are triming a video?

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, avassetexportsession

I am getting wrong video orientation in second time , when I recording a video in landscape mode. for first time record , I am getting correct video orientation in didFinishMediaWithInfo

Right now .I am using following code for detecting video orientation.

```
 AVAsset *firstAsset = [AVAsset assetWithURL:videoUrl];
    AVAssetTrack *FirstAssetTrack = [[firstAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0];

        UIImageOrientation FirstAssetOrientation_  = UIImageOrientationUp;

        BOOL  isFirstAssetPortrait_  = NO;

        CGAffineTransform firstTransform = [FirstAssetTrack preferredTransform];

        if(firstTransform.a == 0 && firstTransform.b == 1.0 && firstTransform.c == -1.0 && firstTransform.d == 0)
        {
            FirstAssetOrientation_= UIImageOrientationRight; isFirstAssetPortrait_ = YES;
        }
        if(firstTransform.a == 0 && firstTransform.b == -1.0 && firstTransform.c == 1.0 && firstTransform.d == 0)
        {
            FirstAssetOrientation_ =  UIImageOrientationLeft; isFirstAssetPortrait_ = YES;
        }
        if(firstTransform.a == 1.0 && firstTransform.b == 0 && firstTransform.c == 0 && firstTransform.d == 1.0)
        {
            FirstAssetOrientation_ =  UIImageOrientationUp;
        }
        if(firstTransform.a == -1.0 && firstTransform.b == 0 && firstTransform.c == 0 && firstTransform.d == -1.0)
        {
            FirstAssetOrientation_ = UIImageOrientationDown;
        }

 if(isFirstAssetPortrait_)
    {
        NSLog(@"Portrait mode");
     }
else{
        NSLog(@"Landscape mode");

}
```

above code giving correct orientation ,If firstly record portrait mode. then record landscape mode. If user again record a video in landscape mode.Then It gives wrong video orientation and make portrait BOOL yes.

If a video is record in landscape mode and trim using AVAssetExportSession . Then trimed video is playing in MPMoviePlayer in wrong orientation .How to resolve this ?

Please guide me.

Answer (score 2):

```
AVURLAsset* movieAsset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL: movieFileURL options: nil];
NSArray *tracks = [movieAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];

CGSize videoSize = CGSizeZero;
if ([tracks count] != 0)
{
    AVAssetTrack *videoTrack = [tracks objectAtIndex:0];
    videoSize = videoTrack.naturalSize;

    CGRect videoRect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, videoSize.width, videoSize.height);
    videoRect = CGRectApplyAffineTransform(videoRect, videoTrack.preferredTransform);

    if (videoRect.size.height > videoRect.size.width)
    {
        NSLog(@"Portrait mode");
    }
    else if (videoRect.size.height < videoRect.size.width)
    {
        NSLog(@"Landscape mode");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Square mode");
    }
}
```

Comment: This was very helpful. Thank you!

Comment: Ok. But what about square video orientation?